# C++ - preserve memory after app has been closed

Tags: c++, caching, memory, memory-management

I have an application in C++ that process data.
Lets say:

```
download dataA - run app to process A
download dataB - run app to process B
...
```

Now I need in B run to have acces to data generated by A. I can store them in a temporary file or DB, but it slows things down. Is there a way how to preserve output from A in memory and open it again in B?

I can not download data and then run the app, it is a serial processing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "but it slows things down" bit? How much data are we talking about? What *kind* of data? And if it's "serial processing" have you thought about using pipes and normal standard output/input?

Comment: It is about 10GB of data, 2D matrix of floats

Comment: Then unless you have at least 10GB or memory available, there's really no way past using files.

Comment: I have 64GB RAM, so there is no problem in this

Comment: By the way, do you *have* to exit the first program to run the second program? Even with 10GB pipes should still be possible, e.g. `./program_a | ./program_b`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS. On Linux you can store the data in shared memory, which is persistent even if no applications are using it. On Windows there is also shared memory, but it will be automatically reclaimed if no applications are using it, so once program A ends, the data will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using with shared memory. It depends on your operating system.

If you are using Windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are using Linux: 
https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html

But there is another option, using Boost.Interprocess facility:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html